# Why won't $_GET work PHP 5.3.21?

Tags: php, get, isset

I'm using $_GET within a switch statement to determine with options to display in a select box. Things were great until I upgraded my server to PHP 5.3.21. Now I get undefined index and undefined variable error messages. I've modified my code to include  if isset(). Now there are no errors, but I can't get PHP to recognize that $_GET["menuid"} does have a value.

URL that I'm trying to get variables from:

http://www.example.com/mod/page/view.php?id=5100&module=1&menuid=2&module=1&page=2

Code I'm using:

```
if (isset($_GET['menuid'])) {
    $menuid = $_GET['menuid'];
}
else {
    $menuid = "not working";
}

echo $menuid;
switch($menuid) {
    // My code
   }
```

The results are:

"not working"

EDIT: Results of `var_dump($_GET)' on the PHP sub page

```
array(0) { }
```

EDIT: Results of `var_dump($_GET)` on the PHP main page

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "5100" ["module"]=> string(1) "1" ["menuid"]=> string(1) "2" ["page"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

The above var_dump is from the PHP main page. The original code is on a separate PHP page that I've included to the PHP main page with a file_get_contents();. Would the file_get_contents() cause this problem?

Comment: Post the results of `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: not workingarray(0) {
}

Comment: From `htaccess` may rewrited. Check `htaccess` rules

Comment: @NickRivers So your problem is that you have no QS variables at all, not just that one. Why...I've no idea. But that's a little more information for someone else to go on.

Comment: Yucky, I was hoping it was a coding error.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that file_get_contents() was making $_GET not work correctly. I've modified my code on the main PHP page to require_once(). A var_dump($_GET) of the sub PHP page, that my original code is on, is now resulting in this:

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "5100" ["module"]=> string(1) "1" ["menuid"]=> string(1) "2" ["page"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Thank you to @Mansfield for you help

Comment: You're welcome! Include/Require is definitely better than `file_get_contents` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two times a "module" defined. I think the right URL looks like this:

http://www.example.com/mod/page/view.php?id=5100&menuid=2&module=1&page=2

Comment: That will affect the 'module' index, not the 'menuid'; you can have duplicate params afaik